# Is it possible that I open a local html file using a method or function in C?

Tags: html, c, linux, ubuntu, path

I have an html file with this path: /home/kevedvoc/index.html

In my C program am scanning the user's input, and if they say "open doc", I want to open this html file on chrome or firefox or whatever browser. I just need it to appear.

How can I do that. Is it doable?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: With firefox or chrome you can do this `/usr/bin/firefox /home/kevedvoc/index.html` to open the page in the browser. You can open it with one of the exec functions or even popen()...

Comment: This is not really specifically a C question, but rather how to request the operating system to open a browser window for a specific URL. You will want to look here: https://dwheeler.com/essays/open-files-urls.html

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while, but if I remember right, you can use `int system(const char *command)` found in `stdlib.h`.

```c
system("firefox <url>"); // "firefox.exe" on Windows.
system("chrome <url>"); // "chrome.exe" on Windows.
```

`system` makes a call to `execl` found in `unistd.h`, so you could also call that directly.